# What do %~df0 and %~df1 mean in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch

I have seen usages of %~df1 in a batch file but I don't know what they mean. I have also seen %~df0 and I think that means the current directory of the batch file but I can't find any documentation on this (bit hard to search for)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

here is a list of common shortcuts:

%~f1 - expands %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt

%~d1 - expands %1 to a Drive letter only - C:

%~p1 - expands %1 to a Path only - \utils\

%~n1 - expands %1 to a file Name, or if only a path is present (with no trailing backslash) - the last folder in that path

%~x1 - expands %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt

%~s1 - changes the meaning of f, n and x to reference the Short name (see note below)

%~1 - expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")

%~a1 - display the file attributes of %1

%~t1 - display the date/time of %1

%~z1 - display the file size of %1

%~$PATH:1 - search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.

The modifiers above can be combined:

%~dp1 - expands %1 to a drive letter and path only

%~nx2 - expands %2 to a file name and extension only

courtesy of [this website](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: See also `if /?`, `for /?`, `set /?`

Comment: What's the `$` dollat sign in `%~$PATH:1`?